# Groovy function call in a closure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

How can I make a function call in a closure in Groovy? Currently trying this but it results in all iterations using the values from the last array element:

```
def branches = [:]
for (int i = 0; i < data.steps.size(); i++) {
    branches["${data.steps.get(i).name}"] = {
        myFunc(data.steps.get(i))
    }
}
parallel branches
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [common gotcha](http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/)

This should work:

```
def branches = data.steps.collectEntries { step ->
    [step.name, { myFunc(step) }]
}
parallel branches
```

Or

```
def branches = data.steps.inject([:]) { map, step ->
    map << [(step.name): { myFunc(step) }]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test that because Jenkins is giving a script security error on the collectEntries method and I can't whitelist it, but I don't doubt it works. The link was very handy, thanks!

Comment: Added a version that uses `inject`